# adb copy apk from system/app using pull command

Tags: android, apk, adb

it is possibile to copy with the command pull an apk from /system/app/ ?
I would copy the player music of my samsung and make the porting of xperia z, it possible this?

Comment: You can probably get the file, but the file you get may well be not only tied to private APIs of the device, but empty of actual dex code as it is likely pre-optimized against their specific details and addresses and stored elsewhere.  There are many open code bases you can *legitimately* start with!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get the list of the packages available:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Get the path of the APK of the specified package name:

```
adb shell pm path com.example.package
```

Get the APK with the path returned from the previous command:

```
adb pull <path_returned>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it would be possible to port on a xperia z?

Comment: It depends if Samsung has used custom libraries available only in TouchWiz version of Android or has used only Android standard API. The only thing to do is try to install the APK

Comment: When I try to install the apk, the message is not installed

Comment: Try to install from adb with `adb install package.apk`. From there you can have more information

Comment: In addition to private API usage the file is quite likely to be pre-optimized, meaning that its actual code is missing but stored elsewhere in a form pre-linked against the system libraries of the devices it was intended for.

Comment: So there is no way to make the porting of default music player of Samsung on a xperia

Comment: where do I type/run the command adb? from terminal in android or from terminal in Ubuntu?